# MATLAB with CVSread for a string (probably easy as I am a beginner)

Tags: string, matlab, csv, matrix

Hey I have a problem where I have two potential ways the input data for a function can be entered.

One way is through a cvs file containing the data, the other is directly through a matrix.

Here is my code to get around this..

```
function printRouteStats(routeData)
    % displays route info basedf on data  for mountain bike tracks
    if isa(routeData,'string')
        gpsPoints = csvread(routeData); %fix this later as currently giving a string
    else
        gpsPoints = routeData;
    end
end
```

This works for say 
printRouteStats([0 0 0; 0 300 10; 100 300 20; 100 500 -10; 400 500 -10])

but for printRouteStats('exampledata.csv') is gives output of exampledata.csv as a string, rather than produce the desired matrix.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Sorry I've only been learning matlab for two weeks so it's probably a really simple question for everyone here.

Answer (score 0):

`class(routeData)` is `char` not `string`. To check use `isa(routeData,'char')` or `ischar(routeData)`